# Moving a existing board to my organisation

Tags: trello

I have an existing board that I have lots of cards in and I want to invite my organisation to be a member.

I can only see creating a new board for my organisation. How do I invite my organisation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can move your existing board into your organization:

```
Menu > Settings > Change Organization
```

[image]

... and then you can choose to make it visible to everyone in your organization

```
Menu > Settings > Permissions > Visibility: Organization
```

If you don't add the board to your organization, you can still invite members from your organization using `Add Members...`

Comment: This appears to have been removed from the UI

Comment: @DavClark it's now under Menu > Additional Settings

Answer (score -2):

Alternatively you can copy your own board to a new board in your organisation so that all the cards remain.

`Copy Board` can be found in Board's Options.

Comment: @snthan that is disappointing. Thanks though.